# Redirecting members with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect members to a different URL. 
From: https://domain.com/member/memberID
To:   https://domain.com/members/memberID

So, everything after members/ should stay the same (logged user ID), the only change is an "s" in member"s"..

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I did some basic redirects from www to non-www before, but what puzzles me here is how to handle redirect when there is a dynamic appending after the last slash. In my case, user ID.. I have no ideas how to set those rules..

Comment: What URL do you want to show to clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect the contents of a whole directory to another use the below:

```
RewriteRule ^member/(.*)$ /members/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: this worked, had to tweak it a bit according to my needs, but it does answer my question. Thanks.